# How do you subtract months from a date field

Tags: formula, formula-field

How do I create a date formula to show on a report 3 months prior to an account anniversary date. I have been playing around with the below formula but I can not get it to work

```
IF(MONTH(  Established_Date__c  ) + IF(MONTH( Established_Date__c-((365/12) * 3), IF(YEAR(TODAY())) - (YEAR( Established_Date__c  )), NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your final intent, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
if ( Established_Date__c.addMonths(-3) <= TODAY() , //show , //not show)
```

Also, here are some of the functions that Salesforce has to help you [deal with dates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the days left to the next account anniversary, you can use this formula:

```
IF (
    DATE(
        YEAR(TODAY()),
        MONTH(Anniversary__c),
        DAY(Anniversary__c)
    ) - TODAY() < 0,
    DATE(
        YEAR(TODAY())+1,
        MONTH(Anniversary__c),
        DAY(Anniversary__c)
    ) - TODAY(),
    DATE(
        YEAR(TODAY()),
        MONTH(Anniversary__c),
        DAY(Anniversary__c)
    ) - TODAY()
)
```

This will return the days until the next anniversary date. It will display 0 when it comes the day! So in your report you can just filter the accounts using this field, getting every account which has 90 or less days left.